# Count the number of displayed elements in a HTML list

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of list items which are display: none by default. I programmatically change a certain number of them to list-items.

I've been trying to use querySelectorAll but when I try:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#ulname style[display*='list-item']")
```

it returns an empty array (I know it is at least one).

Ideas on how to modify my selectors or another approach? I would like to know after the fact how many items are displayed.

Comment: Selectors cannot query elements by style properties. In your code, you're looking for a `style` element in a `ul` element with a `display` attribute containing `'list-item'`, which... makes no sense in HTML. You will need to iterate the child nodes of `#ulname` and find `li` elements whose `style.display == 'list-item'`.

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem. What exactly do you want to do? Change all of them? Just some of them? Is this line of code just trying to determine which are currently displaying?

Comment: @jegesh: The end of the question states "I would like to know after the fact how many items are displayed."

Comment: @BoltClock thanks I was hoping to avoid the iteration to check but what you're saying seems to confirm my own findings. I've seen elsewhere that you can query for CSS selectors could that not be used to query?

Comment: Hmm I don't quite understand your second sentence. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, I was referring to this [MDN - querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) which is where I originally got the idea to use a style selector.

Comment: @Phil querySelector is designed to query attributes of an element, you cannot query css rules. In your case I suggest to use different class names and query elements using specific class names.

Answer (score 10):

```
   var liList = document.getElementById("myul").getElementsByTagName("li");

   var largo = liList.length

   alert(largo);
```

WHERE "**myul**" is the id of the list and **largo** is number of li items

```
<ul id="myul">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>world</li>
</ul>
```

the alert would be 2

```
<ul id="myul">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>world
        <ul>
            <li>here we are</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the alert would be 3

Answer (score -1):

```
    var ul = document.getElementById("myul");
    var liNodes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (ul.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {
            liNodes.push(ul.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }

totalLis = liNodes.length;
```

Adding text to your ul tag

```
var txt = document.createTextNode("gsdgds");
ul.appendChild(txt);
```

Adding li tag to your ul tag

```
var txt = "<li>dsgdsgs</li>";
ul.innerHTML(txt);
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question at all.

Comment: No, thank you for asking. This code says nothing about finding `li` elements that are being displayed. It just gets all the `li` elements. And I see you added some text node and innerHTML examples - I'm not sure how those two things address the question either.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>Maybe this answer can help. I improvise for this after a few days of testing. This is what I got. Hope it helps you.</p>


<li class="sidenav-item open active">
            <a href="#" class="sidenav-link sidenav-toggle" ></i>
              <div class="text-white">Hi, There!
                <div class="badge badge-primary" id="ul-me"></div></div>
            </a>

            <ul class="sidenav-menu" id="ul1">
              <li class="sidenav-item active">
                <a href="#" class="sidenav-link" >
                  <div class="text-white" >Home</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidenav-item" id="ul2">
                <a href="#" class="sidenav-link" >
                  <div class="text-white" >Blog</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidenav-item" id="ul3">
                <a href="#" class="sidenav-link" >
                  <div class="text-white" >Downloads</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidenav-item" id="ul4">
                <a href="#" class="sidenav-link" >
                  <div class="text-white" >Contact</div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="sidenav-item" id="ul5">
                <a href="#" class="sidenav-link" >
                  <div class="text-white" >About</div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
</li>
'''
<!-- Count Item (li) in <ul> -->

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var mylist = [document.getElementById("ul1"), ("ul2"), ("ul3"), ("ul4"), ("ul5")];
  document.getElementById("ul-me").innerHTML = mylist.length;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: writing to `innerHTML` is malpractice.
To get the count of list items here just do `document.getElementById("ul1").getElementsByTagName("li").length;`